How to declare a recursive array type?
I want to create a generic method in TypeScript that takes an instance of a type/class/interface and an array of strings and navigates in a nested manner in the array. More precisely, the method can be something like:
method<T>(instance: T, arrayAttr: someType) {
    let tmp = undefined;
    for (let attr in arrayAttr) {
        tmp = instance[attr];
    }     
    return tmp;
}

and I would like to define the someType to check the types and produce an error if the attribute doesn't exist in the instance.
For example, if for the object:
const obj = {
 attribute1: {
     attribute2: {
        attribute3: "value"
     }
  }
};

the method:
 method(obj, ['attribute1', 'attribute2', 'attribute3'])

should return 'value'. And calling the method with the wrong attributes:
 method(obj, ['attribute1', 'attribute3'])

should produce a compilation error.
I tried something like:
type NestedAttributes<T extends InstanceType, U extends keyof T> =
    U extends keyof T ? T[U] extends InstanceType ? NestedAttributes<T[U], keyof T[U]> : T[U] : never;

but unfortunately, this is not a good solution.

can you provide some example data that you want to work or not?

I just updated them to the question

Would a dot notated string work in the place of an array of properties?  such as method(obj, "attribute.attribute1.attribute2") ?

if that would be possible, of course, but I cannot define it to be checked at compilation

Usually such situations need not the most beautiful approach. Such as determining N overloads up to max required number of parameters.
f.e.:
function method<T, U extends keyof T>(obj: T, attr: U): T[U];
function method<T, U1 extends keyof T, U2 extends keyof T[U1]>(obj: T, attr1: U1, attr2: U2): T[U1][U2];
// and so on...

Also you can use one more "internal" overload to call it recursively:
function method(obj: any, ...params: never[]): never;

So full code for 3 params will look like this:
function method<T, U extends keyof T>(obj: T, attr: U): T[U];
function method<T, U1 extends keyof T, U2 extends keyof T[U1]>(obj: T, attr1: U1, attr2: U2): T[U1][U2];
function method<T, U1 extends keyof T, U2 extends keyof T[U1], U3 extends keyof T[U1][U2]>(obj: T, attr1: U1, attr2: U2, attr3: U3): T[U1][U2][U3];
//...
function method(obj: any, ...params: never[]): never;
function method(obj: any, ...params): any
{
    const currentKey = params[0];
    let res = obj[currentKey];
    const restArgs = params.slice(1) as never[];
    if (params.length > 1) res = method(res, ...restArgs);
    return res;
}


const obj = {
    attribute1: {
        attribute2: {
            attribute3: "value"
        }
    }
};

const a = method(obj, 'attribute1', 'attribute2', 'attribute3'); // ok
const b = method(obj, 'attribute1', 'attribute3'); // compilation error: No overload matches this call

